# Image not showing in server folder

Tags: php, android

I am trying to upload image from my android device to the sever through php.

I am using the following code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
      upLoadServerUri = "http://www.example.com/media/UploadToServer.php";
      messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture);
      imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      uploadButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                 messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {

                          uploadFile(imagepath);

                     }
                   }).start();     
            }
        });
      btnselectpic.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
            }
        });
    }



public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

         dialog.dismiss(); 

         Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                             +imagepath + "XYZIMAGE");

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                         +imagepath + "XYZIMAGE");
             }
         }); 

         return 0;

    }
    else
    {
         try { 

               // open a URL connection to the Servlet
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
             URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

             // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
             conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
             conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
             conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
             conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
             conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
             conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

             dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
             dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=XYZIMAGE;filename="
                                       + fileName + lineEnd);

             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

             // create a buffer of  maximum size
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

             // read file and write it into form...
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

             while (bytesRead > 0) {

               dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

              }

             // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
             dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
             dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

             // Responses from the server (code and message)
             serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
             String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

             Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                     + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

             if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {

                          String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                        +" http://www.example.com/media/uploads/XYZIMAGE";

                          messageText.setText(msg);
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });                
             }    

             //close the streams //
             fileInputStream.close();
             dos.flush();
             dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();  
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                             + e.getMessage(), e);  
        }
        dialog.dismiss();       
        return serverResponseCode; 

     } // End else block
```

And the php code:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

The code runs and also shows the image has been uploaded.
Ideally it should upload to "www.example.com/media/uploads/" but the folder is always empty even tough the images are being uploaded according to the code.

Can you tell me if there is anything in the code which I am missing.
Thank you

Comment: Check folder write permissions.

Comment: in the server? or through android.manifest?

Comment: In the server. The folder must have 755. If that doesn't work, try 777 but that's not recommended, but only a final and last resort.

Comment: Add `chmod("uploads", 755);` just after `$file_path = "uploads/";` see  if that helps.

Comment: You also mention *"Ideally it should upload to "www.example.com/media/uploads/"..."* but your upload folder is `uploads/` that should be `$file_path = "media/uploads/";` if that's what you're trying to upload to. This only applies if you are running your code from the server's root.

Comment: Adding chmod("media/uploads", 0755) freezes the upload process. How do i add the filename also in that code

Comment: You can try setting up a seperate script to modify the permissions, then try the upload after. Call it `setperm.php` and do `<?php chmod("media/uploads", 0755);`

Comment: After that do i call setperm.php from the other php file?

Comment: No, once it's done, you don't need to do it again. The folder will hold the permissions settings.

Answer (score 0):

> "The code runs and also shows the image has been uploaded. Ideally it should upload to "www.example.com/media/uploads/"..."

You are using `uploads` as the uploading folder, where you should be using `media/uploads`

Your present code:

```
$file_path = "uploads/";
```

along with:

```
String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
            +" http://www.example.com/media/uploads/XYZIMAGE";
```

What you need to use (when running code from the root) is:

```
$file_path = "media/uploads/";
```

if outside the root, you will need to use `../`

example:

```
$file_path = "../media/uploads/";
```

depending on the script's location of execution.

To also make sure that the folder has proper write permissions, both folders need to be set to 755.

Example:

`chmod 755 folder_name` in an FTP program.

Comment: I modified my php this way       <?php
  
    $file_path = "media/uploads/";
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?> but still it doesnt work...can i modify my php further?

Comment: @AakshaySubramaniam Are you running the code from the root of the server? This should work. Also, if you can modify the folder(s) permission using an FTP program because of the suggestion I gave you freezes your code, then that would be best.

Comment: Yes I am running from the root folder. Can you guide me through some links which I can follow to change permission through FTP. I am kind of new to android and php. Thanks a lot @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome @AakshaySubramaniam You can visit the following Websites for FTP programs: http://www.smartftp.com/ and http://www.coreftp.com/ and https://filezilla-project.org/ which are good FTP programs. As well as http://www.coffeecup.com/free-ftp/ and http://www.wsftple.com/ which I used in the past.

Comment: There may be another factor at play also, being making sure that the max upload allowed on your server is set large enough. PHP's default I think is 2M. @AakshaySubramaniam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54092/discussion-between-aakshay-subramaniam-and-fred-ii).

Comment: @AakshaySubramaniam Sorry I can't chat, I really have to get some sleep. It's past 3am here.